# encrypting passwords & crypto questions

Tags: encryption

I've read a few articles about encrypting passwords and what I read seems that bcrypt is the way to go.

I know hardly any about cryptography, does it make any difference from the security point of view if I add the username to the password and hash that?

Also does it make sense to create a salt for each user? If my db would get leaked those salts would also be there, should I encrypt the salts too with a global salt?

Does it make sense to also encrypt the user's email adress?

Anywhat what I planned to do is:

```
+use bcrypt
+allow all characters in passwords
+force User to use a digit and special char in his password
+set the minimum password length to 8 chars
```

I'm not building an app which requires mega high security standards but I would like to offer my users some seriouse protection in case my DB gets leaked somehow. ( hopefully it won't )

Comment: Presumably this question is really about hashing passwords (one way) not encrypting them (which would allow you to decrypt them, getting the original value back)? Despite its name bcrypt is often used for the former, not the later.

Comment: yea it's about hashing passwords one way, haven't thought about that regarding my question about hashing the users email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does it make any difference from the security point of view if I add the username to the password and hash that

No added security, especially if you are already using a SALT.  Has the drawback that you have to rehash and persist the hash each time a user changes their username.

> Also does it make sense to create a salt for each user?

Yes, this is commonly done.

> If my db would get leaked those salts would also be there, should I encrypt the salts too with a global salt?

No, do not encrypt them.  The purpose of the SALT is just to force the attacker to have to perform a new brute force search for each user/password, instead of one brute force attack for all.

> Does it make sense to also encrypt the user's email adress?

No.  Unless you have some (strange) business requirement for that.

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to you for asking the question before implementing.  Unfortunately, that's the best point of optimism I have for you.

Security is hard to do right.  *Very* hard to do right, in fact.  If you don't know much about it, then *don't try* until you do.  In the meantime, use a proven infrastructure that does this for you in the (hopefully) correct fashion.  There should be one available for whatever framework you happen to be using, and if there isn't, that may be reason enough to switch.

That said, *dont* use the username for the salt, and don't bother encrypting the salt.  You should also not be encrypting (or hashing) the user's email address, unless you or anyone else will never need to know it (as the maintainer(s) of the system).  And adding the username to the password provides no benefit, and has several drawbacks, so don't do that either.

As far as a unique salt - this is a *must*.  Without it, you might as well not have one.  Read up a bit on encryption, hashing, and salting (and peppering) before proceeding.  Even better, use a library that already does it for you as mentioned before.